# Find a file in python

Tags: python

I have a file that may be in a different place on each user's machine. Is there a way to implement a search for the file? A way that I can pass the file's name and the directory tree to search in?

Comment: See the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories) for os.walk or os.listdir See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229186/os-walk-without-digging-into-directories-below for sample code

Answer (score 347, accepted):

[os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) is the answer, this will find the first match:

```
import os

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)
```

And this will find all matches:

```
def find_all(name, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
```

And this will match a pattern:

```
import os, fnmatch
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

find('*.txt', '/path/to/dir')
```

Comment: Note that these examples will only find files, not directories with the same name. If you want to find **any** object in the directory with that name you might want to use `if name in file or name in dirs`

Comment: Be careful of case sensitivity. `for name in files:` will fail looking for `super-photo.jpg` when it's `super-photo.JPG` in the file system. (an hour of my life I'd like back ;-) Somewhat messy fix is `if str.lower(name) in [x.lower() for x in files]`

Comment: What about using **yield** instead of preparing the result list? .....
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
          yield os.path.join(root, name)

Comment: Please consider updating your answer to Python 3.x primitives

Comment: While this is the solution for Python, finding a file this way is about 5 times slower for me than forking and exec'ing `find`. Compare for yourself with: `os.popen('find / -name stdio.h').read().strip()`

Comment: Comprehention list can replace the function, e.g. find_all: res = [os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) if name in files]

Comment: Is there a way to make it search for a pattern, but list only the first instance (ie, combination of first match and pattern match code)?

Comment: @JoshuaDetwiler yeah but you're using python... who cares about performance?

Answer (score 52):

In Python 3.4 or newer you can use pathlib to do recursive globbing:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> sorted(pathlib.Path('.').glob('**/*.py'))
[PosixPath('build/lib/pathlib.py'),
 PosixPath('docs/conf.py'),
 PosixPath('pathlib.py'),
 PosixPath('setup.py'),
 PosixPath('test_pathlib.py')]
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

In Python 3.5 or newer you can also do recursive globbing like this:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Comment: glob working great. And we don't need to list a directory as a parameter if we are searching in the current directory

Comment: Excellent answer. It is also possible to glob for a relative path, e.g., `glob.glob('**/path/to/data/*.txt', recursive=True) -> ['/pwd/path/to/data/2.txt', '/pwd/path/to/data/sub/3.txt']`
By default, `glob.glob()` uses `os.getcwd()` as root dir.  Later versions of Python allow root dir override.  Else, use `os.chdir()` to set PWD, then glob, glob, glob!

Answer (score 28):

I used a version of `os.walk` and on a larger directory got times around 3.5 sec. I tried two random solutions with no great improvement, then just did:

```
paths = [line[2:] for line in subprocess.check_output("find . -iname '*.txt'", shell=True).splitlines()]
```

While it's POSIX-only, I got 0.25 sec.

From this, I believe it's entirely possible to optimise whole searching a lot in a platform-independent way, but this is where I stopped the research.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Python on Ubuntu and you only want it to work on Ubuntu a substantially faster way is the use the terminal's `locate` program like this.

```
import subprocess

def find_files(file_name):
    command = ['locate', file_name]

    output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    output = output.decode()

    search_results = output.split('\n')

    return search_results
```

`search_results` is a `list` of the absolute file paths. This is 10,000's of times faster than the methods above and for one search I've done it was ~72,000 times faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with Python 2 you have a problem with infinite recursion on windows caused by self-referring symlinks.

This script will avoid following those. Note that this is **windows-specific**!

```
import os
from scandir import scandir
import ctypes

def is_sym_link(path):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915819
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x0400
    return os.path.isdir(path) and (ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesW(unicode(path)) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)

def find(base, filenames):
    hits = []

    def find_in_dir_subdir(direc):
        content = scandir(direc)
        for entry in content:
            if entry.name in filenames:
                hits.append(os.path.join(direc, entry.name))

            elif entry.is_dir() and not is_sym_link(os.path.join(direc, entry.name)):
                try:
                    find_in_dir_subdir(os.path.join(direc, entry.name))
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    print "Could not resolve " + os.path.join(direc, entry.name)
                    continue

    if not os.path.exists(base):
        return
    else:
        find_in_dir_subdir(base)

    return hits
```

It returns a list with all paths that point to files in the filenames list.
Usage:

```
find("C:\\", ["file1.abc", "file2.abc", "file3.abc", "file4.abc", "file5.abc"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Below we use a boolean "first" argument to switch between first match and all matches (a default which is equivalent to "find . -name file"):

```
import  os

def find(root, file, first=False):
    for d, subD, f in os.walk(root):
        if file in f:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(file, d))
            if first == True:
                break
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very similar to existing ones, but slightly optimized.

So you can find any files or folders by pattern:

```
def iter_all(pattern, path):
    return (
        os.path.join(root, entry)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
        for entry in dirs + files
        if pattern.match(entry)
    )
```

either by substring:

```
def iter_all(substring, path):
    return (
        os.path.join(root, entry)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
        for entry in dirs + files
        if substring in entry
    )
```

or using a predicate:

```
def iter_all(predicate, path):
    return (
        os.path.join(root, entry)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
        for entry in dirs + files
        if predicate(entry)
    )
```

to search only files or only folders - replace “dirs + files”, for example, with only “dirs” or only “files”, depending on what you need.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

SARose's answer worked for me until I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The slight change I made to his code makes it work on the latest Ubuntu release.

```
import subprocess

def find_files(file_name):
    command = ['locate'+ ' ' + file_name]
    output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
    output = output.decode()
    search_results = output.split('\n')
    return search_results
```

Comment: Python itself is able to find files without using subprocess to Unix commands

Answer (score 1):

@F.M.F's answers has a few problems in this version, so I made a few adjustments to make it work.

```
import os
from os import scandir
import ctypes

def is_sym_link(path):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915819
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x0400
    return os.path.isdir(path) and (ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesW(str(path)) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)

def find(base, filenames):
    hits = []

    def find_in_dir_subdir(direc):
        content = scandir(direc)
        for entry in content:
            if entry.name in filenames:
                hits.append(os.path.join(direc, entry.name))

            elif entry.is_dir() and not is_sym_link(os.path.join(direc, entry.name)):
                try:
                    find_in_dir_subdir(os.path.join(direc, entry.name))
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    print("Could not resolve " + os.path.join(direc, entry.name))
                    continue
                except PermissionError:
                    print("Skipped " + os.path.join(direc, entry.name) + ". I lacked permission to navigate")
                    continue

    if not os.path.exists(base):
        return
    else:
        find_in_dir_subdir(base)

    return hits
```

unicode() was changed to str() in Python 3, so I made that adjustment (line 8)

I also added (in line 25) and exception to PermissionError. This way, the program won't stop if it finds a folder it can't access.

Finally, I would like to give a little warning. When running the program, even if you are looking for a single file/directory, make sure you pass it as a list. Otherwise, you will get a lot of answers that not necessarily match your search.

example of use:

find("C:\", ["Python", "Homework"])

or

find("C:\\", ["Homework"])

but, for example: find("C:\\", "Homework") will give un-wanted answers.

I would be lying if I said I know why this happens. Again, this is not my code and I just made the adjustments I needed to make it work. All credit should go to @F.M.F.