# Does Python os.walk(...,followlinks=True) work in WIndows (Vista)?

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

I have a simple directory containing just 2 links to other directories.
os.walk does not walk into them, it reports 2 files and 0 directories.
I note the docs refer to "symlink" which I suspect is a Unix term not MS but Im not sure.
Or is there something else im missing?

[Python 2.7 on Vista Pro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work on Windows (at least in Windows 7).

`followlink` depends on `os.islink`, `os.isdir`. But both returns `False` for Link directory in windows (in Python 2.7).

BTW, in Python 3.2+, `os.islink` return `True` for symlinks. But `os.isdir` still return `False`. `os.walk` does not work neither.

See [os.path.islink on windows with python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259028/2225682).

Comment: Is there a work around?   Signed, Kludges R Us. :).  I mean simpler than what's suggested in the link?   In the alternative, is there any reason not to move to 3.2?   I am on another project using Google App Engine which came with 2.7, not sure if 3.2 is supported.

Comment: @RFlack, I don't know another workaround. IMHO, You need to implement your own version of `os.walk` because `os.isdir` still returns `False` for symlinks.

Comment: @RFlack, Python 3.x has slightly different syntax. And some libraries does not support Python 3.x (yet). You should first check libraries your are using support Python 3.x.

Comment: One wonders how many people have made enhanced walk procedures...  Also, I'm curious as to the rationale for this behaviour, assuming there is one.

Comment: @RFlack I would bet there is no rationale. this is pure lack of canonicalization, and riguor. NT supports at least junctions since 2000. boost filesystem has put more thought into that than the python team it seems. in the end they decided to remove all of it because of the difficulty of canonicalizing (abstracting concepts between OS) in these cases.