# Python os.walk thinks a windows shortcut is a file - how can I make it follow the shortcut?

Tags: python, shortcut

While technically a network shortcut is a file, it prevents `os.walk()` from traversing the directory.
I've created a shortcut that maps `C:\Data\Sale` to `\\\filesrv\saledata`.
I run the script:

```python
import os
      dir = "C:\Data"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir, topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      print("file")
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
   for name in dirs:
      print("directory")
      print(os.path.join(root, name)) </code>
```

and I get:

```
file

C:\Data\Sale
```

No internals of `\\filesrv\saledata` are listed.  How can I make `os.walk()` work with a Windows shortcut?  UNC path isn't working either.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. Here you can find more information

https://bugs.python.org/issue1578269

[Does Python os.walk(...,followlinks=True) work in WIndows (Vista)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585495/does-python-os-walk-followlinks-true-work-in-windows-vista)

Comment: Answers that are simply links to other answers are discouraged. If you think this question is exactly answered in another post, flag / vote to close this one as a duplicate. Please read [answer] and the links therein, and take the [tour].

Comment: I disagree a bit @PranavHosangadi. This answer has link to Python bug which doesn't exist in another post in SO. Helpful answer.

Comment: @ex4 then it falls afoul of the [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that guideline. But this one isn't just a link answer. It has information that that is a known bug and then link for reference. According to guidelines answer should give specific answer for the question in the post. In this case question is "how can I make it follow the shortcut". "it is known bug" isn't exact answer to that question, but reader get info that it cannot be done until the bug is fixed. But there could be a bit more info written to the answer, that is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a way for os.walk to access a remote directory is to create a mapping using **"net use"** command: **net use z: \...**.  Then os.walk can traverse through that.