# How to tell if a directory is a windows junction in python

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, symlink

I am running `os.walk()` on `"C:\Users\confusedDev\Documents"`, I see `["My Music", "My Pictures"...]` returned as subDirs but they are not actually being visited. After some research I found that they are actually [junctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows.

My understanding is that junction is a symlink points to directory, which gets ignored by default during `os.walk()`, but the following test has failed me

```
>>> os.path.islink("C:\\Users\\confusedDev\\Documents\\My Pictures")
False
```

hmm...how did `os.walk()` know that "C:\Users\confusedDev\Documents\My Pictures" is a symlink to "C:\Users\confusedDev\Pictures" and needed to be skipped? I want to call the same api...For now, my workaround logic simply assumes that if a directory is skipped by `os.walk()`, it is a junction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.path.islink on windows with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258506/os-path-islink-on-windows-with-python)

Comment: The implementation of `os.[l]stat` is internally inconsistent. For `follow_symlinks` it handles any reparse point as a link, instead of correctly limiting this to just symlinks and [some] junctions. Additionally, when creating the stat result, it accepts only symlink reparse points for the `S_IFLNK` mode flag, which is what `islink` checks. It should also accept junctions, but only when they implement a legacy link, i.e. *not* when the target is a "\\?\Volume{...}" mountpoint for which `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint` would succeed.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki, he is talking about Windows `junction links`, not symbolic links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links. they are not the same in windows.. and `islink` returns false even in Python3 for `junction links`. Any idea how to check `junction links` in python?

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but you can wrap os.readlink() in a try and except for directory junctions, and then put that in a function you could call, like this:

```
def is_junction(path: str) -> bool:
    try:
        return bool(os.readlink(path))
    except OSError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way that I'm going to use is subprocess. Just calling the external windows program that gives info about links in Windows, return you a 0 as return code if link exists, and other if doesn't exists or is not a link:

```
fsutil reparsepoint query "<PathToTest>"
```

Something like this for example:

```
src = "C:\\Windows"
child = subprocess.Popen(
    "fsutil reparsepoint query \"{}\"".format(src),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
streamdata = child.communicate()[0]
rc = child.returncode

if rc == 0:
    print("Link exists")
```

On Windows 10 works fine as a normal user (also create links), but for Windows 7 you needs Admin Rights. For me is not a problem, because my application will check the link to create a new one, so it needs Admin Rights on Windows 7 anyway.

Greetings!

Comment: Thank god, you are the only, only, only one totally correct without using win32 library or ctypes which is not reliable.  Thank you very much .  I 've been using "dir" for a while.  And finally I get your decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `python3.5`, `islink` returns false for `junction links`. It seems `python3.5` doesnt natively support junction links, but support for junction links can be added using `ctypes` or external libraries:

1. Using external module for ntfs: https://github.com/Juntalis/ntfslink-python/tree/master/ntfslink
2. Using win32 module in pywin32: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32file__CreateSymbolicLink_meth.html
3. directly calling dlls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143276/4752883

These are more involved solutions. Further, if you use `junction links`, they wont work on previous versions of windows or on other OSes.

**TL;DR** To make it portable, it may be better to instead convert your `junction links` to `symbolic links` using `mklink /D` instead of `mklink /J`. `symbolic links` are recognized by `os.walk` and `os.path.islink`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.isjunction(path)` to check if the path is a directory junction.

needs at least python 3.12

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isjunction

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to know if it is linked, you can use [pathlib.Path().resolve()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) like:

```
path = Path('somedir')
if path.absolute() != path.resolve():
    print(f'{path} is a link to {path.resolve()}')
```

if you then check [is_symlink()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_symlink) to exclude symlinks, you're left with junctions or hardlinks.

haven't figured out a good way to exclude hardlinks, but for all of my use-cases, knowing if it was a link, was sufficient.