# Printing the complete path of a file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find the complete path of a file (name is user input) within a computer. I tried `os.path.dirname(filename)` and `os.path.abspath(filename)`, but all it does is return the path of the file added to the current working directory.

For example, let `IntelGFX.txt` be a file with path `C:\Intel\Logs\IntelGFX`, but the path I get on using `os.path.abspath('IntelGFX')` is `C:\Python34\IntelGFX`.

So how do I get the original path of the file?

Comment: Please don't roll back legitimate edits - we make them for a reason (in this case: 1. to fix the formatting; and 2. The first paragraph and *"THANKS!!"* were just pointless noise).

Comment: @jonrsharpe it seems i misunderstood the meaning of rollback. I thought rollback would edit my version of the question and present your edited version as the final question.

Comment: No, *exactly the opposite*; it removed my edit and restored your original version. As a user with >2k rep my edits don't go into the review queue, which may be what you're confusing this with.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to search the filesystem for a file with the given name? This will not be quick, depending on the number of files you have to search through.

You might like to try using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). You can use it to walk over all the files from a given root directory. In the following I use it to find all the directories called "tests" in my python install location.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
from itertools import chain

target = "tests"
path = "c:\\Python34"

found = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in chain(files, dirs):
        if name == target:
            found.append(join(root, name))

print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

> all [`abspath`] does is return the path of the file added to the current working directory

Well, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> On most platforms, [`abspath`] is equivalent to calling the function [`normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

so this *is* the expected behaviour. Think about it - where *should* Python be looking if you just give it a filename? You can't just expect it to start searching everywhere for it!

If that's the behaviour you want, you will need to implement it explicitly; see e.g. [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1724693/3001761).