# What does this syntax mean: paths = [line[2:] for

Tags: python

My using python only occasionally; so I understand the basic concepts; but today I ran into a piece of code ... that I simply don't understand:

I was looking for an efficient way to do "find" via python; and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) shows this answer:

```
paths = [line[2:] for line in subprocess.check_output("find . -iname '*.txt'", shell=True).splitlines()]
```

And yes, it works for me; and is much faster compared to os.walk; so I intended to use it. But I have to admit: I don't understand what it is doing; especially the 'line[2:]' part ... wtf?!

I tried to use google/so to find the answer; well, searching for "python line" didn't help at all ... so, probably stupid question: what does it mean?

Comment: What is happening is you are slicing the `./` off the strings returned from the `find` command, find will return `'./filename'`, slicing the first two chars off removes the `./` so you are just left with the filename, it is strings returned that are being sliced not lists

Answer (score 6):

`line[2:]` is using [slice-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to make a sub-string of `line` from element `[2]` to the end of the string.

This is wrapped in a list comprehension that will do the above operation for every line that was returned from `subprocess.check_output`