# How to Search in Windows with Python subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen, explorer

- How can **[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)** be used to open a specific local or network directory **in Windows File Explorer**, and search for image file names with a specific string.
- In this case, the requirement is:

  - Only display specific images (out of many), **in File Explorer**, for a quick visual verification.
- For this purpose, **I am not interested** in knowing how to search Windows with `os` or `pathlib`. Those methods are clearly explained in [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Note: **Search locations must be `indexed` by Windows**

  - Look in `Control Panel` for `Indexing Options`

```py
import subprocess

query_string = 'file_name.png'
local_path = r'C:\Users\your_name\Pictures' # r is raw for dealing with backslashes
network_path = r'\\your\network\fold\path'

# for a network location
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer /root,"search-ms:query={query_string}&crumb=location:{network_path}&"')

#for a local folder
subprocess.Popen(f'explorer /root,"search-ms:query={query_string}&crumb=folder:{local_path}&"')
```

1. `subprocess.Popen` is from the Python standard library [Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).
2. `search-ms:parameter=value[&parameter=value]&` is from MSDN [Getting started with parameter-value arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684385(v=vs.85).aspx).

- Parameter-value arguments can be configured in a variety ways not exclusive to the way shown here.  For example, folder will only locate local folders, but location will work for network and local folders.

3. `f'some_string {variable}'` is from PEP498: Formatted String Literals.
4. `explorer` &  `/root` are Windows commands.