# How to find if a directory exists somewhere (I dont know the path ) in my computer from a python script

Tags: python

Suppose there is a directory somewhere in my computer (I don't know its path) and I don't want to search it by myself rather I want my script to find it out by itself using the 'directory name' (provided no ambiguity) and if it exists then how can I import files from that into the script.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `os.walk()` and `importlib`

Comment: Sounds a bit like this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Care to elaborate what your questions background is?

Comment: Sure. so I have a script from which I have to run a batch file and this batch file is in another directory in my computer (I know where it is but I want the script to find it by 'dir name') and once it finds that directory exists I want to import the batch file into the script from which I want to run it. Any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) ... Searching for directory/path name is essentially the same as searching for a file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
import fnmatch
import os

dir_name = 'untitled'
matches = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("C:/"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(dirnames, dir_name):
         matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

print (matches)
```

result:

['C:/Users\user\Desktop\untitled']