# Trying to figure out why the loading time of my pages is too slow

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-admin

I'm setting up a script and I'm trying to figure out why I'm forced to wait 60 seconds for the loading of my pages. I've developed a platform where I display some information about a file (its image and its details).

At the moment, I display the data of 10 folders containing around 10000 files each.

---

I'm using the Flask framework and FileAdmin to load my files. I've tried to analyze the time of each function in my code and I've obtained this:

```
all_the_files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.*") >>>>>>>> around 0.01s
```

```
for file in all_the_files:
   if '_ex' in str(file):
     try:
       filename = str(file).split('/')[-1]
       file_part1 = filename.split('_')[0]
       file_part2 = filename.split('_')[1]

>>>>>> around 1e-05s for each
```

```
found_file = [file for file in all_the_files if re.match("^"+filename+".*", str(file).split('/')[-1])]
image_path = [file for file in found_file if re.match("^"+filename+".*"+"\.png", str(file).split('/')[-1])][0]
txt_path = [file for file in found_file if re.match("^"+filename+".*"+"\.txt", str(file).split('/')[-1])][0]

>>>>> around 0.02s for each file
```

---

With these time records, I know that the third function is too long for each file.

How can I manage to reduce the loading time of my pages?

Comment: I've already used a SSD

Comment: don't you think its normal for 3 loops?

Comment: The first loop is relative to the whole folder, but the next are just relative to the first one which contains maximum 3 strings. I'm forced to loop 3 times, I didn't find another way to realize that.

Comment: try using fie,file1,file2 .... etc instead of just one variable file

Comment: and even post regex, so that others can make it simpler.

Comment: I'll update my question.

Comment: One possible optimisation: replace `str(file).split('/')[-1]` with `str(file).rpartition('/')[-1]`.    Also, I don't think you need to call `str` on the filename each time - the output of `glob.glob` is a list of strings.  A higher level optimisation, if your code cannot be made fast enough,  might be to cache the computed data in memory and render your page using that data unless a the content of the directories is modified.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find files whose names match specific patterns.  If so, [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) might be faster.  See [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) for an example similar to what you are doing.

Comment: I've tried using os.walk(), the algorithm is longer than before.