# Most efficient way for searching all files with the same filename in python

Tags: python, glob, file-search

I want to find the extensions for all files with the same name in a folder. So for example, if a directory contains 2 files named test.csv and test.txt. I want the program to return a list containing ".txt" and ".csv".

I have used:

```
glob.glob(file_name + '*')
```

which works but is quite slow (0.03 seconds) when the folder contains many files. Is there some faster way of doing this in python?

Comment: this should help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python

Comment: Maybe you can use SO commands to lookup, like (ls *file_name* or with find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like :

```
import re
import os

files = os.listdir(".")

my_files = re.findall(r"(\w+\.php)", " ".join(files))

print(my_files)
```

Comment: Does this not assume I know the extensions in advance?

Comment: just an example you may use r"(MY_NAME\.\w+)" dpends on what you want to match

Comment: Yup that worked. I have no idea how you knew that searching the regex strings would be faster but it did indeed make it doubly fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with file names as keys and extensions as values as follow:

```
import os
data = {}
for file in os.listdir():
    name, ext = file.split('.')
    if name not in data.keys():
        data[name ] = list()

    temp = data[name].copy()
    temp.append(ext)
    data[name] = temp

print(data)
```

Comment: This takes .0.1 sec for almost 200K files