# Searching through my pc to check if i have a file with a certain name using python?

Tags: python

file searching

---

how would imake a program that would check if my pc had a file with a certain name no matter what type the file is  and then print yes or no.
For example i would put in a file name then it would print if i had it or not. ive tried similar things but they didnt work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `os` module for this.

```
import os

def find(name, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name) # or you could print 'found' or something
```

This will find the first match. If it exists, it will return the file path, otherwise it returns `None`. Note that it is case sensitive.

This was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) answer.

Comment: where do i specify the name of the file im looking for? 

thanks for the answer

Comment: @rocks2260 When you call the function. Example: `find('name_of_file.file_extension', 'path/to/folder')` If you want to see the results just wrap that in a `print()` statement.

Comment: thanks for the help, 1 more quick thing. say i wanted to search in this pc directory so its the whole pc would i put 'This PC' with no slashes.

Comment: @rocks2260 there's no way to search the whole PC in one shot, you'll have to go to the root of each disk individually: 'c:\\', 'd:\\', etc.

Comment: @rocks2260 like @Mark Ransom said, searching with `C:/` or `D:/` is as low as you can go.

Comment: alright, so what would i do to search say downloads?
This PC/downloads?

Comment: @rocks2260 `C:/Users/Owner/Downloads` probably

Comment: @rocks2260 if you can find the folder in the file explorer click here [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8rfp.png) to see the file path. then just copy/paste :)

Comment: when i put in C:/Users/Owner/Downloads because of the C: it wont let me put it in ' '
also thanks for all the help

Comment: dw i fixed that issue, new one is that def find_files ('Autoclicker.exe', 'E:\coding' ):
im getting an invalid syntax at the first ' and the file path is highlighted red along with the '):

Comment: @rocks2260 try `'E:\\coding'` or `E:/coding`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Pathlib module. The code written using Pathlib will work on any OS.

```
#pathlib will work on any OS  (linux,windows,macOS)
from pathlib import Path 

 # define the search Path here  '.' means current working directory. you can specify other path like Path('/User/<user_name>')
search_path = Path('.')
# define the file name to be searched here.
file_name = 'test.txt'
#iteratively search glob() will return generator object. It'll be a lot faster.
for file in search_path.glob('**/*'): 
    if file.name == file_name:
        print(f'file found =  {file.absolute()}') #print the file path if file is found
        break
```