# Getting an input from the user then searching it in a folder in Python

Tags: python, file

I was working on a Python project which would help my dad organize his job better.
I want to get an input from the user,then searching it in the folder which is in same folder my Python file is.Like,for example, a pseudo-code

```
searchfile = get_input
search(searchfile)
if is_in_the_same_folder{
    print searchfile
}
else{
   print "This file cannot be found"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code expected to do? You say: "searching it in the folder..." What do you mean by this?

Comment: To find if that input exists in the folder as any file type

Comment: should it match any name exactly, or should the input string be a subpart of the filename?

Comment: it should match exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python)