# checking if any mp3 files exist in a specified directory

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system

I want to use python to check if any mp3 files exist in a specified directory. If it does exist, I want to store the file path in a variable.

Here is some code I have to check if any file exists. How can I modify it?

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.'
dir_path = os.path.join(dir, '../folder/')
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, f))]
```

Comment: "How can I modify it" is not a helpful question. What are you trying to accomplish, what have you tried, and how is it not working? You got the first part, now answer the second and third!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the additional condition `f[-4:]==".mp3"` to the `if` statement within your list comprehension such that it now reads:

```
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, f)) and f[-4:]==".mp3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

dir = os.path.dirname("/path/to/your/dir/"); dir_path = dir;
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, f)) and f[-4:]==".mp3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the `pathlib` module better so I'm going to post an answer using it. Keep in mind though that this isn't a recursive approach so it's only going to go one level down and search for the `.mp3` files you want:

```
import pathlib as path

dirname = path.Path(input("Enter the path to the directory to search: ")).glob("*.mp3")
paths = []

for file in dirname:
    paths.append(str(file))
```

I stored the paths in a list instead just in case there were more `.mp3` files in the folder.