# How do I delete a file from a folder in Python?

Tags: python, delete-file

I do know about `os.remove()` I am working on - When an excel file is created into a folder then the script runs and it will add the excel file data into the particular columns of the table of database. What I want is the file should be deleted from that folder just after running the script so that when a new excel file is created into the folder the script will again runs and add the new data into the database and so on. I am a newbie to the python and as I know `os.remove` needs file name to be entered.

Is there any other function of doing this? Here is my script

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import os
import xlrd

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        connection = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=xyz; HOSTNAME=xyz; PORT=xyz; PROTOCOL=xyz; UID=xyz; PWD=xyz;","","")
        conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(connection)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        query = "INSERT INTO EXCELUPLOAD (qty, amt, num, code, name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"

        for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                qty  = sheet.cell(r,0).value
                amt  = sheet.cell(r,1).value
                num  = sheet.cell(r,2).value
                code = sheet.cell(r,3).value
                name = sheet.cell(r,4).value
    
                values = (qty, amt, num, code, name)
                cur.execute(query, values)
    
        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler()

observer.schedule(event_handler, path=r'D:\New folder')
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: So what you really want to do is [find a file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python)?

Comment: If you just want to delete any files , you could use a wildcard in your filepath like /a/path/*.*

Comment: Also, please share your code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've edited my question and also shared my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `os.listdir()` to list all files of a given folder.

Then you could either delete all files or delete files based on their file name or file type/suffix.

E. g.:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

files = os.listdir("your/path")
for file in files:
    os.remove(file) # delete all files

    if Path(file).name == "Test" or Path(file).suffix == ".txt":
        os.remove(file) # delete file based on their name or suffix
```