# Python function to check whether it is a file or a dir

Tags: python

I have listed all directories and files of a given path by using `os.listdir()`

I want to see the element in the list is a file or directory, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in os library as well:

```
os.path.isdir()

os.path.isfile()
```

Example:

```
import os

root = "C:\\"
for item in os.listdir(root):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, item)):
        print item
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.path.isdir`.

And always beware race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) you get the filtering between files and directories for free and you can also process the directory recursively.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
  process_dirs(dirs)
  process_files(files)
  break # If you only want to process the first level or take a look a the commend below
```

Comment: However if you only care about the top directory that would be a lot slower and require more work, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229186/os-walk-without-digging-into-directories-below).