# Loop through directories and cd to only the first dir under each

Tags: python

```
rawsource="/Users/user/project/CODE_BASE"  
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rawsource):
    print(root)
```

This is printing like 4-5 levels deep of paths like:

```
/CODE_BASE/website/.git/info
/CODE_BASE/website/.git/refs/remotes/origin
```

I just want to print:

```
/CODE_BASE/website
```

for example.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

---

*UPDATED .. this prints out paths 4-5 levels deep like shown above*

```
def walklevel(some_dir, level=1):
    some_dir = some_dir.rstrip(os.path.sep)
    assert os.path.isdir(some_dir)
    num_sep = some_dir.count(os.path.sep)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(some_dir):
        yield root, dirs, files
        num_sep_this = root.count(os.path.sep)
        #if num_sep + level <= num_sep_this:
        #    del dirs[:]
        print(root)
list(walklevel(rawsource))[0]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/234329/12502959 help?

Comment: Any easier alternative @python_learner ? e.g. `print(dirs[0])` ? anything easier than what you suggested? Thanks

Comment: well you can convert that generator to a list and then index? something like `list(walklevel('/Users/user/project/CODE_BASE'))[0]`

Comment: If I try that though, it still prints out the 4-5 levels deep. see updated. rawsource is set to `/CODE_BASE`

Comment: Any thoughts @python_learner ? Thanks

Comment: ohh hey, sorry I was away, will update if I find a better alternative