# Get the names of first folders only inside a directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, operating-system

I am trying to iterate through a folder, where inside it, I will be having multiple other folders, each could contain other subfolders. An example of the tree could be:

```
Dataset_Directory
  | Folder A
  | Folder B
  | Folder C
  | Folder D
      | Folder D1
      | Folder D1
```

What I am trying to do is to only get the man 4 foulders, which are A,B,C,D and ignore any sub-folders.

My code:

```
    folders = [os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(x[0])) for x in os.walk(
        app.config['DATASET_DIRECTORY']) if x[0] != 'static\Dataset_Directory']

    for folder in folders:
        print(folder)
```

This outputs all folders and sub-folders inside the list as os.walk gets all from the directory tree. The output is as follows:

```
Folder A
Folder B
Folder C
Folder D
Folder D1
Folder D2
```

What I'm trying to achieve is only

```
Folder A
Folder B
Folder C
Folder D
```

Any suggestion on how to stop it from reading through sub-folders? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.walk without digging into directories below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229186/os-walk-without-digging-into-directories-below)

Comment: you don't need to use `os.walk()` if you don't want to recurse.

Comment: `_, mainfolders, _ = next(os.walk(data_directory))`

Comment: Thanks, @blorgon for your suggestion, working perfectly but would be a bit computational if running on a server as in my case.

Comment: @JohnGordon answer was perfect for my case, thank you.

Comment: Just use `os.listdir` and filter out files if that's a problem

Answer (score 2):

You can also utilize the pathlib library as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path
print([x.name for x in Path('Dataset_Directory').iterdir() if x.is_dir()])
```

**Yields:**

```
['Folder A', 'Folder C', 'Folder D', 'Folder B']
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**

```
import os.path
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('Dataset_Directory') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('Dataset_Directory', d))]
print(dirs)
```

**Output:**

```
['Folder A', 'Folder C', 'Folder D', 'Folder B']
```